# How to write a Python script to automate API calls and retrieve a specific part of the result

Tags: python, pandas, geocoding

I have a csv file of schools that contains one school per row for a total of 32091 schools. The name of the school is indicated in the 6th column, and the city code is indicated in the 7th column.

I would like to retrieve the latitude and longitude of the schools by using the geocoding API of the IGN (Institut Géographique National de France) whose documentation in French is here: https://geoservices.ign.fr/documentation/services/api-et-services-ogc/geocodage-beta-20/documentation-technique-de-lapi-de

This API allows me to indicate a string of characters as search terms, and to restrict the search with a filter on the city code. I have tested several queries and the results seem to be satisfactory. For example, for the school "ecole primaire privee st joseph de bonabry" located in Fougères (city code 35115), the following query:

```
https://wxs.ign.fr/essentiels/geoportail/geocodage/rest/0.1/search?q=ecole%20primaire%20privee%20st%20joseph%20de%20bonabry&index=poi&limit=1&returntruegeometry=false&postcode=35300
```

returns the following json:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "postcode": [
          "35300"
        ],
        "citycode": [
          "35115",
          "35"
        ],
        "city": [
          "Fougères"
        ],
        "toponym": "École Primaire Saint-Joseph de Bonabry",
        "category": [
          "area of activity or interest",
          "primary education"
        ],
        "extrafields": {
          "cleabs": "SURFACTI0000000215529805",
          "names": [
            "saint joseph de bonabry elementary school"
          ]
        },
        "_score": 0.703030303030303,
        "_type": "poi"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.19610139955834,
          48.3550652629677
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So the coordinates to extract are located here: `{"features":[{ "geometry":{"coordinates":[lon, lat]}}]}`

I would like to go through a Python script to automate the task. From what I understand, the steps could be as follows:

- Open the CSV
- Read the value contained in the sixth column
- Perform an http get request for each row, changing the URL based on the value in the sixth column
- Extract longitude and latitude from the results
- Update the longitude and latitude columns (already existing) with the previously extracted values.

Panda allows me to read the CSV while Requests allows me to formulate the query. Being a beginner in programming I don't really know how to write the script. I guess it can start this way:

```
import panda as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
```

...but I'm stuck on what to do next. I guess a loop would allow to repeat the request but how do you change the URL terms? In general, any help on the whole scrit will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.
Replace "name" and "post" with the actual column names from your CSV

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# read the data CSV
# you have to replace "name" and "post" with the actual column names
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols=["name", "post"])

# define the request URL
url = "https://wxs.ign.fr/essentiels/geoportail/geocodage/rest/0.1/search"

#api call for each element
for i in range(len(df["name"])):
    # prepare the name for URL
    genName = df["name"][i].replace(" ", "%20")
    print(genName)
    # prepare request
    request = url + "?q=" + genName + "&index=poi&limit=1&returntruegeometry=false&postcode=" + str(df["post"][i])
    print(request)

    # do the request
    r = requests.get(request)
    # response
    result = r.text
    print(result)
```

Comment: Thank Goldenfaeron, it's working great. To read the csv properly I added the separator at the end of df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols=["name", "post"], sep=";"). Now I need to find out how to extract a specific value in the json and write it into the csv.

Comment: Yes. Use the python JSON library to acces data from the result. [W3Schools JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) and then use pandas again for writing. [Pandas Doc for wiriting](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)